# Need to display a character '-' based on a string length in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a hangman game and what I want to do is make the minus/dash symbol '-' appear the number of times for the string length of the randomly chosen word from an array.
So far what I have is:
HTML:

```
    <h1>Hangman</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
        <div style="margin-left: 100px;">
            <p id = "word">     </p>
           <div id="image"></div>
        </div>
```

then in my js file I have:

```
    var randomWords = ['rock','paper','scissors'];

    document.onkeyup = function(event) {

    var chosenWord =    randomWords[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomWords.length)];

      // var blankLines = "";//(1)

     for (int x = 0; x < chosenWord.length; x++)
     {
         // blankLines += '- '; //(1)
         // document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = blankLines;
         // document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = ;
     }
         //document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = blankLines;//(1)
```

None of the commented out methods worked. The (1) means that these lines go together when I tried it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not targeting ES6, this is just as easy:

```
chosenWord.replace(/./g, '-')
```

Comment: Thank you for input, I am very new to javascript and have not learned this .replace method nor do i know what (/./g that whole section does and I dont know what ES6 is. We have not covered any of this in class. Is there a way to do it using very beginner basic syntax?

Comment: ES6 is [ECMAScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) 6, which is a standard for JavaScript. We are currently somewhere between ECMAScript 5 and ECMAScript 6, as most popular browsers implement most of the new ES6 things, but not all yet. There is also ES7 in the works, but its features are largely not available yet.

Comment: OMMGG. I just figured out I had the int x = 0 in the for loop. I am in C++ mode.... Wow. Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: `replace` is a method on strings that replaces substrings with something else. What I search for here is `/./g`, which is a [http://regular-expressions.info/](regular expression) for "any one character" (`.`), globally (`g`) - i.e. find all characters, replace with a dash.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```js
var dash='-', x="",chosenWord="sdsjdj";
for (var i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i++)
{
  if(i!=(chosenWord.length-1)) {
    x=x+dash+" ";
  }
  else {
    x=x+dash;
  }
}
console.log(x);
```

Comment: `if (i < chosenWord.length - 2)` is a bit shorter. And you can use `x += dash`. Or you can loop until `u < chosenWord.length - 1`, so you can just do `x += dash` after the loop to simplify the code much more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting [ES6](http://es6-features.org/) you can simply use the `repeat` function:

```
"-".repeat(chosenWord.length);
```

If you are targeting non-ES6 (older browsers), you can do a "hack" like below:

```
Array(chosenWord.length).join("-")
```

Or you can use more descriptive code like this:

```
var dashes = "";

for (var i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i++) {
    dashes = dashes + "-";
}
```

Comment: well I am very new to javascript so the .repeat and Array(chosenWord.length).join("-") is unfamilar to me and we have not covered it yet in class. And I am not sure what ES6 is. Is there a way to do it using very beginner basic syntax? But thank you I will try it out.

Comment: ES6 is a newer form of JavaScript. It gives you some new features, but it isn't supported in older browsers. If you are a beginner, the third example (for loop) in my answer will probably be best for you :)

Comment: I tried this method: var dashes = "";

for (var i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i++) {
    dashes = dashes + "-";
} but I did dashes += "-" then did the document getlement ID innerhtml = dashes but it did not work. Both inside and outside of loop

Comment: OMMGG. I just figured out I had the int x = 0 in the for loop. I am in C++ mode.... Wow. Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: green tick? where is that?